# Does a finite state machine have to use all the input?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

I'm trying to make a finite automata but am unsure about this detail. If the machine reaches the goal state before the input is finished, can the machine accept or does it have to continue going if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is that the FSM must use all the input - otherwise there could be no finite regular languages.